# Google Sheet custom function - update cell references when the sheet is modified/the formula is copied to new cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom formula, code below, to extract the URL of cells containing hyperlinks. I need to do this for a whole bunch of cells, so I need to ensure the reference cell is correct.

However, I have to explicitly type out and manually modify the cell reference every time I use the corner drag function to expand the formula to other cells, as well as every time a row is added or deleted, etc - the reference doesn't smartly update the way it does for built-in functions.

Is there a way to update the script or otherwise induce Sheets to smartly update the cell reference?

**Custom function script:**

```
function GETLINK(input){

return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(input).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();

}
```

**Starting sheet example:**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Index | Cells with hyperlinks | Formula |
| 1 | Link Text 1 | =GETLINK("C1") |
| 2 | Link Text 2 |  |

If I click and drag the corner of C2, I wanto see this output:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Index | Cells with hyperlinks | Formula |
| 1 | Link Text 1 | =GETLINK("C1") |
| 2 | Link Text 2 | =GETLINK("**C2**") |

But instead I get this:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Index | Cells with hyperlinks | Formula |
| 1 | Link Text 1 | =GETLINK("C1") |
| 2 | Link Text 2 | =GETLINK("**C1**") |

^ the same kind of non-updating happens if I happen to insert some rows/cells - the references just stay absolute and don't intelligently update.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
=GETLINK(CELL("address", C1))
```

Then add this function in your script to remove the `$` returned by the `CELL()` function:

```
function GETLINK(input){
  var rangeName = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeName).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
}
```

References:

- [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [CELL(info_type, reference)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267071?hl=en)

Comment: This did the trick, thank you so much!!
I did make a slight addition as shown below, to ensure an empty value was returned in cases where there wasn't a URL value to serve, since that's what I needed for my use case:

function GETLINK(input){
  var rangeName = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
  
  if(rangeName == undefined) {
    return "";
  } else {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(rangeName).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
  }
}